# Django order by manytomany field using custom method

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I get all services ordered by discount__value where discount.is_active()?

## models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    long_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    active_from = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    active_to = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    review_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    discount = models.ManyToManyField(Discounts, null=True, blank=True)

class Discounts(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    active_from = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    active_to = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def is_active(self):
        return (self.active_from is None or self.active_from <= date.today()) and \
               (self.active_to is None or self.active_to >= date.today())
```

In my view I have

```
filtered_services = Service.objects.filter(not important)
services = filtered_services.annotate(highest_discount=Max('discount__value')).order_by('-highest_discount')
```

So in services I have all services ordered by maximum discount of all discounts (that are relevant for each service) but I want all services ordered by discount__value where discount.is_active()?

So how can I get all services ordered by discount__value where discount.is_active()?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you can declare is_active as a `@property` and filter by `discount__is_active=True`

Comment: I don't want to filter. I need all services... but within all services I want to order by discount value...using just discounts that are active... (so if I could apply filter in this second phaze it would be great...but I don't know how)